# C++ code analysis tools which deals with well known mistakes

Tags: c++, code-analysis

Currently I am programming a lot with C++. Sometimes I stumble over the specific issues of the language C++. It is often very hard to deal on one the hand with the *application domain* to solve a specific problem programmatically and to deal on the other hand with the issues of C++.

An example:

```
class Animal {

public:
    Animal ();
    Animal (const char* name);
    virtual ~Animal();

    const char* getName() const;

private:
    char* _name;

};
```

In this class I have a pointer as member. So I will create it dynamically in the constructor and delete in the destructor.

The problem is, that if I don't specify a Copy-Constructor myself, the generated Copy-Constructor will only copy the pointer *itself* to the new Copy-Object. Which means that any changes to the data which is pointed by one pointer of these objects will be available for every copied object. So I have to define a Copy-Constructor **and** the assignment operator myself to copy the value pointed by the pointer.

```
Animal::Animal(const Animal& other)
{
    if(_name) {
        delete [] _name;
    }
    _name = new char[strlen(other.getName()) + 1];
    strcpy(_name,other.getName());
}
```

Another C++ specific issue: 
if I don't make the Descructor `virtual` the destructors of the subclass are not called if I use `delete` on a super type.

There are so many things in C++ which produces often so many problems which are hard to find.

**Are there any code-analysis tools which can search for problems like this and show some hints, which could possibly wrong at one point?**

Comment: Please. Use. `std::string`.

Comment: Which operating system are you working on?

Comment: And `std::vector` instead of dynamically-allocated raw arrays, and smart pointers instead of manually calling `new` and `delete`. Problems related to raw pointers are pretty much solved.

Comment: If on Windows, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97454/c-static-code-analysis-tool-on-windows You might find more benefit from writing unit tests for your application, though. (and as others have said, don't write C++ code as if you were writing C!)

Comment: Windows 7 but sometimes Linux. So any platform independent tool would be great! I often use Eclipse to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any code-analysis tools which can search for problems like this and show some hints, which could possibly wrong at one point?

Yes, there are lots of [tools for static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B). Some (like [parasoft's tool](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/cpptest.jsp?itemId=47)) you can configure in details to catch all kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can be a *great* source of help in finding problems statically. For example I use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-long-long -pedantic -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wnon-virtual-dtor` which catches a wide variety of code problems.

The second thing you can do is write C++, not C. Use RAII to manage your resources and preferably let someone else write the code that has to do explicit management (for example smart pointers and standard containers). This way the compiler can implicitly generate correct copy semantics automatically, preventing an entirely separate set of problems.

Comment: -Woverloaded-virtual can also be very useful. GCC 4.7 with override and final is not yet available.

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/632057/183203) includes a lot of good answers for this.  Top result googling C++ and lint.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Fanael's advices.

Enable most warnings in your compiler and treat them as (potential) errors.

On static code analysis, read this: http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/12/24/static-code-analysis/

Also, cppcheck is a free and a cross-platform tool, give it a try.

Comment: Thx, I first learned Java and then C and now I try a lot with C++, so sometimes I still use "the old C-Style" which is bad indeed. I try to learn more about smart-pointers, boost:: and the string library of C++ etc.